# If a static variable is declared out side of a function, will the memory address be the same as if it's declared in a function

Tags: c, static-memory-allocation

I was asked these 2 questions during an interview. I guess the address of a static variable will be the same no matter where it is declared. It will also have the same address from run to run. Correct me if I am wrong.

1. If a static variable is declared out side of a function, will the memory address be the same as if it's declared in a function?
2. If a static variable is declared out side of a function, will it have the same address every time you run the program?

Comment: Unless the company develops compilers or embedded systems, consider yourself lucky to have not known the answer. This rings of some overly clever engineer _scoring points_ by trying to trip-up candidates.

Comment: You can also answer back to the interviewer that static variables should be used with care as they trigger reentrance problems in multithreaded environments.

Comment: This is a reasonably terrible question.  It's sort of like asking, "If John kisses Mary, will she love him back, or slap him?"  (It is, at best, a question to inspire discussion, *not* one with any kind of definitive yes/no answer.)

Comment: Most probably the interviewer was not interested in an actual answer, but wanted to watch you handling this question. This soft skill is more important than expert level knowledge that you can easily research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cunningham's Law will ensure quick correction of my mistakes:

1. global and local static variables are treated similarly so they may indeed end up at the same address when moved:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef GLOBAL
static int i;
#endif
// static int j;

#ifndef GLOBAL
void f(void) {
    static int i;
    printf("local:  %p\n" , (void *) &i);
}
#endif

int main() {
#ifdef GLOBAL
    printf("global: %p\n" , (void *) &i);
#else
    f();
#endif
}
```

You need to disable address randomization to observe it:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'echo 0 >  /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space';\
gcc 1.c && ./a.out &&\
gcc -DGLOBAL 1.c && ./a.out;\
sudo bash -c 'echo 2 >  /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space'
local:  0x555555558034
global: 0x555555558034
```

If you add another global `static int j` (commented out above) after the global `i` then  the effect goes away:

```
local:  0x555555558038
global: 0x555555558034
```

So [call me maybe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWNaR-rxAic)!?

2. No.  Modern operating systems, specifically the program loader, use address space layout randomization
   (ASLR) so the address changes on every execution:

```
$ ./a.out && ./a.out
global: 0x563bcce14034
global: 0x55cd4a497034
```

Comment: You might use a `(void *)` cast for strict portability, especially since `i` has type `int`: `printf("local:  %p\n" , (void *)&i);`

Comment: Whether these variables are stored in the `bss` segment depends on other factors: they might have an initializer and get stored in a `data` segment, or be `const` and end up in a `text` segment...

Comment: @chqrlie Fixed. I realize that`%p` requires a `void *` but why is the explicit cast necessary?  I mean, I guess, pointers to different types may differ.  The only thing I found in the standard was that  it's convertible back and forth.

Comment: pointers may have different representations and be passed differently as function arguments, including vararg functions. Casting to `void *` ensures the pointer is passed in the way expected by `printf`. Note however that most modern systems use the same representation for all pointer types and this is  mandated by the POSIX standard. Some older systems such as the Cray One supercomputer used to have a different representation (and size) for `int` pointers and `char` pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`static` variables may or may not have the same address in memory when declared globally or locally in the body of a function. The fact is nothing can be assumed about these addresses: the C Standard only guarantees that they compare different from the null pointer and different from the addresses of other data objects defined in a C module (albeit compiler extensions can force some symbols to alias one another).

Modern operating systems use address randomisation to make it more difficult for attackers to exploit software flaws, so the addresses may indeed differ from one run to another.

Answering such questions in an interview is tricky: the interviewer's assumptions might be outdated, but a substantiated answer should get you a good mark.